# ASP.NET Core 2 get cookies from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, cookies, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-2.1, httpclientfactory

currently I am working on a Project written with ASP.NET Core 2 and I am trying to get a JSON file from a third party website. The problem is that this website requires a few cookies in order to retrieve data from it. I implemented a typed HttpClient in my Startup.cs file like this:

```
    services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseCookies = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
        };
    });
```

Is there any way of accessing the CookieContainer to use the CookieContainer.GetCookies() method, so that I can copy various cookies like the Session Cookie and some verification tokens from the HttpResponseMessage?

Sorry if I am making something wrong, this is my first post.

**EDIT**

Got it to work by adding a HttpMessageHandler in the Request Pipeline

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpClient, MyHttpClient>()
                    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyMessageHandler>();
```

and edit the http header information in the HttpMessageHandler

```
public class MyMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly CookieContainer _cookies;

    public MyMessageHandler()
    {
        _cookies = new CookieContainer();
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_cookies.Count == 0 && message.RequestUri.Host.Contains("example.com"))
            {
                // Simulate the Request
                var getCookieMesssage = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/"),
                    Content = message.Content,
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                };

                // Simulate User Agent
                foreach(var agent in message.Headers.UserAgent)
                {
                    getCookieMesssage.Headers.UserAgent.Add(agent);
                }

                var testResponse = await base.SendAsync(getCookieMesssage, cancellationToken);

                if (testResponse.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out var newCookies))
                {
                    foreach (var item in SetCookieHeaderValue.ParseList(newCookies.ToList()))
                    {
                        var uri = new Uri(message.RequestUri, item.Path.Value);

                        // Add parsed cookies to CookieContainer
                        _cookies.Add(uri, new Cookie(item.Name.Value, item.Value.Value, item.Path.Value));
                    }
                }
                // Add parsed cookies to the header of the HttpRequestMessage
                message.Headers.Add("Cookie", _cookies.GetCookieHeader(message.RequestUri));
            }
            // get response
            var response = await base.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return response;
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }

}
```

This approach gets all cookies from the Set-Cookie header and adds it to the Cookie header of the request.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyClient` is a custom implementation of `HttpClient` you can overload the constructor to store a reference to the `HttpClientHandler`:

```
public MyClient(HttpMessageHandler handler) 
       : base(handler)
{
    Handler = handler;
}

public MyClient(HttpMessageHandler handler, bool disposeHandler) 
       : base(handler, disposeHandler )
    Handler = handler;
)

public HttpMessageHandler Handler { get; }
```

Comment: Did any of the constructor get hit (if you set a breakpoint there?

Comment: Your approach did not work for me, because MyClient was no custom implementation of HttpClient but a typed HttpClient instance from the HttpClientFactory which comes with ASP.NET Core 2 Framework. I used the following way to implement it:
[link](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore)
This is why your approach did not work for me, but I am very thankful for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from your edit isn't clear so I've summarised it here.
Also, there is no need for explicitly setting `HttpClientHandler.UseCookies = true` or for having a `CookieContainer`.

To get the cookies from the call, you can simply read the `"Set-Cookie"` response header:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
IEnumerable<string> cookies = response.Headers.SingleOrDefault(header => header.Key == "Set-Cookie")?.Value;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:44330/api/Records",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType:"json",
            data: JSON.stringify(formdata),
            // Fetch the stored token from localStorage and set in the header
           headers: {"Authorization":'Bearer '+data.data.token},
            success: function(datas) {}
          });
```

Comment: Hello, this question was answered by myself. Your answer does not supply a valid solution, because what you wrote is JavaScript and the question asks for asp.net core which is written in C#